# I am changing RTL(Urdu) to LTR but after conversion its meaning got lost

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am changing RTL(Urdu) to LTR but after conversion its meaning get lost. For example if I am writing "prograaming kee duniya mein aapaka svaagat hai" in Urdu that is in RTL when it get converted I am getting "jamaraabila mula agar kab abraam" but is there any way after conversion the meaning remain same

I have tried these two pieces of program source code:

```
from bidi.algorithm import get_display


rtl_text = "مرحبا بك في عالم البرمجة"  # prograaming kee duniya mein aapaka svaagat hai
ltr_text = get_display(rtl_text)

print(ltr_text)  # jamaraabila mula agar kab abraam
```

Second piece of code:

```
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
from arabic_reshaper import arabic_reshaper

def display_text(text):
    reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(text)
    bidi_text = get_display(reshaped_text)
    print(bidi_text)

text = "مرحبا بك"  # RTL text
display_text(text)
```

Comment: There is a `language` parameter for `arabic_reshaper.reshape` and it supports Urdu. Can you try that?

Answer (score 0):

Create an ArabcicReshaper instance and pass language value via configuration options while creating the instance:

```py
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
from arabic_reshaper import ArabicReshaper
def display_text(text):
    config = {"language": "urdu"}
    reshaped_text = ArabicReshaper(configuration=config).reshape(text)
    bidi_text = get_display(reshaped_text)
    print(bidi_text)
display_text("مرحبا بك")
display_text("مرحبا بك في عالم البرمجة")
```